# Bmp, как получить доступ к пикселям изображения?

Tags: bmp, c++

Здравствуйте! Не получается определить цвет пикселя в bmp, да и вообще сомневаюсь, что пытаюсь определить цвет пикселя, а не какого-то "мусора" в картинке... Открываю файл на бинарное чтение и считываю в массив... Пиксел занимает 4 байта, похоже 3-BGR, а 4-й на что так и не понял... И какоий байт R, какой G... не известно, вообщем мешанина... картинка 2х2 пикселя... Открыл ее в WinHex, понял что картинка начинается с offset=54. затем идет нечто такое:

```
...
   1 54 00 -где тут пиксел цвета RGB???? 
     55 00
     56 00
     57 ff

   2 58 26
    59 00
    60 00
    61 ff

   3 62 24
     63 1c
     64 ed
     65 00

   4 66 ff
     67 4c
     68 4c
     69 ff
```

На сколько я понял, если поменять тетрады местами, то и цвета поменяются... Ничего подобного не происходит... Цвета смешиваются, появляются новые и прочие фокусы...

И вот вопрос, в картинке эти тетрады соответствуют этому(экспериментально да, но всё же):

```
34
12
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Читайте спецификацию.

> > И вот вопрос, в картинке эти тетрады соответствуют этому(экспериментально да, но всё же):

да, строки идут снизу вверх. Если один пиксель занимает 3 байта (да, такое может быть), а длина строки - 5 пикселей (путь так), то строка будет занимать не 15 байт, а скорее всего 16. Последний байт - пустышка, его значение не важно. Это делается для удобства поиска пикселей. По английски это называется `stride` (большой шаг).

По поводу пикселей. Нужно по заголовку посмотреть, сколько байт идет на пиксель. Может быть 1, 2, 3 или 4 (а то и больше) (это 28-29 байт). В случае с двумя байтами на пиксель, цвета могут кодироваться в формате 444 или 565.

Но пиксели ещё могут быть упакованы с помощью rle.

Comment: Пытался понять, найти информацию об этих RGB...4 байта на пиксел... После 54-го байта идет информация о картинке до 69-го.. Больше ничего нет, "вроде и пустышек" нет...

Comment: `69-54 = 16 байт` если учесть, что 4 байта на пиксель, то все совпадает. Но, спросите - а где же ещё один байт я взял, ведь 69-54 = 15???. Все нормально.  Разница то 15, но байт 16. Посчитайте.  размещение - по три байта пиксель, а в конце строки 0-3 байта пустышек. (В Вашем случае будет 2 байта в конце до кратного 8)

как размещены цвета - BGRBGRXX - одна строка. То есть, в случае красного Вы должны увидеть такую строку `00 00 FF 00 00 FF 00 00` (это строка на два красных пикселя).

Comment: Ну. спасибо, всё получилось...

Comment: в самом простом случае - до кратного 4. Но в целом - посмотрите внимательнее заголовок - там есть поле biSizeImage. Оно указывает в байтах размер изображения. Если его разделить на biHeight, то получим кол-во байт на строку. Дальше сможете? но смотрите, biHeight  может быть отрицательным:)

Comment: Перечитайте мой последний комментарий.

`00 00 00 ff 00 00 ff XX` - видимо слева были ещё байты? и их суммарное количество было кратно 4.

Comment: я не понимаю вопроса. слова не связаны логически. переформулируйте.

Comment: Как получить из бинарного файла высоту картинки? Да и вообще как получить любое число?